# matplotlib rc colorcycle argument with scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have configured my own colorcycle in my rc-file (axes.color_cycle) which works fine for the `plot` command but not for something like:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.scatter(x[i],y[i],s=area[i], alpha = 0.5)
```

any ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to loop in order to use `.scatter`. You can prepare a list of colors and provide it with `color=` to `scatter`. The `color` method is implemented in such a way that the list of colors does not need to match the length of the data, it gets automatically repeated/cycled or truncated if necessary.

So for example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

n = 50
x = np.random.randint(0,100,n)
y = np.random.randint(0,100,n)
area = np.random.randint(20,100,n)

ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, alpha=0.5, color=mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'])
```

Results in:

[image]